# Change label color when textarea has value

Tags: css, sass, textarea

I need to change color of label when textarea receiving some value.

```
<form action="#" class="form-reverse">
   <textarea name="order-background__bussiness" id="order-background__bussiness" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
   <label for="order-background__bussiness">What are the company’s objectives?</label>
</form>
```

When we focusing textarea it works fine with this code:

```
textarea:focus ~ label{
        color: #55c57a;
}
```

[image]

But, I need this color: color: #ff8086; when we don't have any values, and green one(as on image above) when anything written on textarea.

I've tried :active , but it works only when Mouse clicked:

```
textarea:active ~ label{
        color: #ff8086;
}
```

[image]

Maybe someone has a solution for this?

PS: I do have a solution for this with JS , but I'm curious if there is any solution with SASS as well?

Comment: I dont think that u can do something with just css/sass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the css valid property, it will match if the textarea is a valid field you can set the required attribute and it will match the valid selector if valid...
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_valid.asp

```css
textarea:valid + label{
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<textarea required="required"></textarea><label>label</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like this, this will work fine as above:

```
 textarea:not(:invalid) + label{
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One further option, that avoids making the `<textarea>`, and other form elements, `required` is to use the `:placeholder-shown` pseudo-class; this does, of course, require that a `placeholder` attribute be set (although it can be set to a whitespace, or zero-length, string):

```
/* selects a <label> element immediately adjacent to
   an element which has its placeholder string visible
   to the user: */
:placeholder-shown+label {
  color: #f90;
}

/* this selects all <label> elements, but is less specific
   than the selector above; so will be 'overridden' in the
   event that the previous selector matches: */
label {
  color: limegreen;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.form-reverse {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30vh;
}

:placeholder-shown+label {
  color: #f90;
}

label {
  color: limegreen;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="form-reverse">
  <textarea name="order-background__bussiness" id="order-background__bussiness" placeholder=" "></textarea>
  <label for="order-background__bussiness">What are the company’s objectives?</label>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ums0zad6/).

References:

- [`:placeholder-shown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown) <sup>([Selectors Level 4 spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#placeholder))</sup>.